# Regex for jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have to turn all the error containing line within 'p' element to red. Basically if there is a error it will start with a space(not always) & 3 or more asterisk mark(always).

For e.g:

```
*** ERROR[14567] Manager initialization failed.

 ***** error[14567] Manager initialization failed.
```

My Code:

```
<script>
    $('p').each(function(){

$this.html($this.text().replace(/(\s)*[*]*(\s)*ERROR.*/ig, '<span style="color: red;">$&</span>'));

</script>
```

But this is not working. Kindly help.

Comment: Asterisk is reserved symbol for regexp.  You should escape it by slash. Try change [*] to [\\*]

Comment: `$this` is not defined

Comment: I m sorry .. I had declared it in the script but forgot to mention it here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the ***containing line*** but something similar to this should work

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  $(this).html(function(index, current){
    var wrap = '<span style="color: red;">$&</span>';
    return current.replace(/\s*?\*{3,}\s*?error.+/gi, wrap);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>*** ERROR[14567] Manager initialization failed.</p>

<p>
  first line
  ***** error[14567] Manager initialization failed.
  other line</p>
```